# image_type_to_extension Control with if

Tags: php, image

I am using PHP GD library to resize my images. I want in to resize only JPG or JPEG files beacuse I am getting an error for the PNG ones. I have tried to use image_type_to_extension function but still no chance.

```
function CroppedThumbnail($imagename, $imgwidth, $imgheight)
{
    if (image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_JPEG)) {
        // Set a maximum height and width
        $width = $imgwidth;
        $height = $imgheight;
        // Content type
        //header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        // Get new dimensions
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imagename);
        $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;
        if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
            $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
        } else {
            $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
        }
        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        // Output
        $newFileName = 'small/' . $imagename . '';
        imagejpeg($image_p, $newFileName, 100);

        return '/' . $newFileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `image_type_to_extension` jsut returns a string like `.jpg` or `.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to determine the type of the photo according to the name.

```
if(exif_imagetype($imagename)===2){  // 2 means jpg and jpeg
...
...
...
}
```

replace this with your `if(image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_JPEG)) { }` in your code

[just have a look](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)